# What does it mean to “plumb” an IP address?

Tags: ip, networking, ip-address, network-theory

Plumbing an IP address means what? What are some examples of it?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, it’s just another word for multi-homing a device (such as a server), with the caveat that it’s done on the same link rather than separate links.  It’s generally a bad practice because multi-homing mostly accomplishes 2 things:

1. It wastes IP addresses needlessly (in most cases)
2. It creates a layer 2 security risk because you now have direct paths on multiple networks with typically no filtering (because most environments filter layer 3 but not layer 2), and because if anyone breaches that host they can now easily move laterally across the rest of the hosts on the same networks.